# multiple attributes being affected at once

Tags: python, class

When I change the `stats.hp` or `base_stats.hp` value for the `Creature` class, it always sets **both** values at once, which is a problem because it means I cannot reset the creature's hp to it's base value. Here's some of the code that deals with this

```
class Stats:

    def __init__ (self,hp,height,strength,speed,skill,agility,perception):
        x = random.randint(-2,2)
        self.hp = hp+x
        x = random.randint(-10,10)
        self.height = height+x
        x = random.randint(-2,2)
        self.strength = strength+x
        x = random.randint(-2,2)
        self.speed = speed+x
        x = random.randint(-1,1)
        self.skill = skill+x
        x = random.randint(-2,2)
        self.agility = agility+x
        x = random.randint(-2,2)
        self.perception = perception+x

class Creature:

    def __init__ (self,name,stats,top_image,side_image):
        self.name = name
        self.base_stats = stats
        self.stats = stats
        # More code here for rest of attributes
```

Maybe the problem is because the `Creature.stats` and `Creature.base_stats` are referencing the same `stats` variable?

(edit)

The `stats` referenced in the `__init__` of the Creature class is a `Stats` object

Comment: Yes, they are referencing the same `stats` variable.  Assign to copies to avoid that behavior

Comment: Is  there a way of copying the stats without having to make two identical `Stats` objects? Especially since I'm also semi-randomising the stats, and this might either cause problems or just not work exactly how I want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. They reference the same object. You could use [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html), instead.

```
from copy import copy
self.base_stats = copy(stats)
self.stats = copy(stats)
```

Answer (score 0):

the stats in your `__init__` function is an object of Class Stats correct?  therefore you are assigning the SAME object to self.base_stats and self.stats.  So any update to either of those will affect the other because you are changing the ONLY Stats object that your creature has as an attribute.

```
class Creature:

    def __init__ (self,name,stats,top_image,side_image):  
        self.name = name
        self.base_stats = stats
        self.stats = stats
```